# Getting error "No Vertex attrib is enabled in draw call" on glDrawElements

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on an Android app that uses OpenGL ES 2.0. When I try to render my primitives from the array data with the following line...

```
// primitiveType is a GLenum with a value of 1
// batch->GetIndexCount() returns a size_t with a value of 65528
// indexType is a GLenum with a value of 5123
// Passing 0 as the indices parameter since an ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER is bound (0 will be treated as an offset within the buffer)
GL_CHECK(glDrawElements(primitiveType, static_cast<GLsizei>(batch->GetIndexCount()), indexType, 0));
```

I get the following error:

```
I/Adreno-ES20: <validate_vertex_attrib_state:55>: validate_vertex_attrib_state: No vertex attrib is enabled in a draw call!
W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glDrawElementsInstancedXXX:1014>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
D/libEGL: [glDrawElements] 0x501
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #00 pc 00002a31  /system/lib/libbacktrace.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #01 pc 0000ba41  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::CallStack::update(int, int)+52)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #02 pc 00025ff5  /system/lib/libEGL.so
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #03 pc 000cea14  /data/app/com.sample.openglesapp/lib/arm/libgl_code.so (OpenGLESHelper::DrawBatch(OpenGLESApp::Graphics::PrimitiveBatch*)+720)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #04 pc 00129038  /data/app/com.sample.openglesapp/lib/arm/libgl_code.so (RendererOpenGLES::Render_DrawBatch(OpenGLESApp::Graphics::PrimitiveBatch*)+52)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #05 pc 000d4b80  /data/app/com.sample.openglesapp/lib/arm/libgl_code.so (OpenGLESApp::Graphics::RendererBase<OpenGLESApp::Graphics::Rendering3D::Camera>::Render()+532)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #06 pc 00161bd8  /data/app/com.sample.openglesapp/lib/arm/libgl_code.so (RenderFrame()+344)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #07 pc 00161cc0  /data/app/com.sample.openglesapp/lib/arm/libgl_code.so (Java_com_sample_openglesapp_GL2JNILib_step+20)
D/glGetError:glDrawElements: #08 pc 000db0e1  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.sample.openglesapp@base.apk@classes.dex
```

According to the OpenGL ES 2.0 documentation, [glDrawElements returns a GL_INVALID_VALUE error code](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) when the count (second parameter) is negative, which is not the case here. Also, the vertex attributes are enabled.
What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: Doesn't the title of your question answer it? It's pretty clear what is wrong. If it's not that then please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it's impossible to help when we can't see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Go over your vertex shader.

If syntax or calculation is wrong in your vertex shader, you can see the message “No Vertex attrib is enabled in draw call”

or

If your one of indices refers to wrong number it can happen.